# Is there a common technique for drawing a "stretchy" line

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to figure out how to draw an stretchy/elastic line between two points in openGL/Cocos2d on iPhone. Something like this

[image]

Where the "band" get's thinner as the line gets longer. iOS uses the same technique I'm aiming for in the Mail.app, pull to refresh.

First of all, is there a name for this kind of thing?

My first thought was to plot a point on the radius of the starting and ending circles based on the angle between to the two, and draw a quadratic bezier curve using the distance/2 as a control point. But I'm not a maths whizz so I'm struggling to figure out how to place the control point which will adjust the thickness of the path.

But a bigger problem is that I need to fill the shape with a colour, and that doesn't seem to be possible with OpenGL bezier curves as far as I can tell since curves don't seem to form part of a shape that can be filled.

So I looked at using a spline created using a point array, but that opens up a whole new world of mathematical pain as I'd have to figure out where all the points along the edge of the path are.

So before I go down that rabbit hole, I'm wondering wether there's something simpler that I'm overlooking, or if anyone can point me towards the most effective technique.

Comment: Just a thought: I don't think you need splines/bezier here. Look at the curvature, it looks like a small part of a very large circle, which runs through the the very top and bottom of each end point circle. So perhaps you can find a way to "stamp out" the squeezed part with circles. The more the two end points are stretched apart, the smaller the radius of the stamp circles.

Comment: Cheers, Although looking closer at the default iOS "pull to refresh" blob thing, it's definitely not using that approach. But I'll gove your suggestion some investigation.

Comment: Did you find a name for this thing?

Comment: Nope - which I guess presents us with a golden opportunity to leave our mark on history. May I suggest - Booger™

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about a "common" technique that people use, other than calculating it mathematically, but this  project,   **[SlimeyRefresh](https://github.com/dbsGen/SlimeRefresh)**,   is a good example of how to accomplish this.